Display flash message in handler
I work in Symfony 7 application where I use rabbitmq for process file. I would like the handler display a message / flash message in the twig template when message is received in the handler.
The goal is to display a message when the message is curretnly process and when the message is receive by the handler I would like to display the result of the message in the page.
Is this possible ? Thank you
My handler :
#[AsMessageHandler]
final class StatusMessageHandler
{
    private $notifier;

    public function __construct(NotifierInterface $notifier)
    {
        $this->notifier = $notifier;
    }

    public function __invoke(CSVFileMessage $message)
    {
        $this->notifier->send(new Notification('Thank you for the feedback; your comment will be posted after moderation.', ['browser']));
    }
}

Twig :
   {% for message in app.flashes('notification') %}
        <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible fade show">
           {{ message }}
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
       </div>
    {% endfor %}


You need to inject the session service into your StatusMessageHandler class, then you can add a flashmessage

@DarkBee My handler is async and i consume message with the command "php bin/console messenger:consume async" . I don't know if is possible to inject session service in async

If it's async you will need to resort to another storage, e.g. database. Flashmessages depend on a session

Okay thank you ! There is another possibility to display or send message / notification to the browser without database ?
